# Having trouble instantiating object on the correct height

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using a FSMDeathState to determine that when the enemy dies, it will drop a certain buff, depending on a generated number, problem is, since the model has it's pivot on the feet, the buff gets instantiated on the ground, how can i change this?

Here's the code

```
public void DeathState(){

        if(randomBuff == 1){
        Rigidbody instanced = Instantiate(dropHpBuff, enemyDropPoint.position, enemyDropPoint.rotation) as Rigidbody; 
    }else if(randomBuff == 2){
        Rigidbody instanced = Instantiate(dropAtkBuff, enemyDropPoint.position, enemyDropPoint.rotation) as Rigidbody; 
    }else if(randomBuff == 3){
        Rigidbody instanced = Instantiate(dropDefBuff, enemyDropPoint.position, enemyDropPoint.rotation) as Rigidbody; 
    }
        GameObject.Destroy(gameObject);

}
```

Comment: Add a Vector3 offset on top of `enemyDropPoint.position`, or add a special GameObject on the enemy for where you'd like to have the buff appear and use its position instead of the drop point's position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep an `Empty GameObject` at the position you like, name it `DropPoint`. You can do this in the `Editor`. Then you can find it and keep a reference to it.

```
private Transform dropPoint;   

void Awake()
{
    dropPoint = transform.Find("DropPoint");
}

public void DeathState()
{
    if(randomBuff == 1)
       Instantiate(dropHpBuff, dropPoint.position, dropPoint.rotation); 
}
```